# How to display chinese characters in PDF using ITextSharp in c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, chinese-locale

I want to display one word of chinese characters in PDF along with english characters. Currently chinese characters are not getting displayed in PDF.I have used itextsharp to generate pdf with contents.I have tried some chinese fonts but not working. How to show chinese characters along with english characters in PDF using itextsharp?

```
var docIndex = new Document(new Rectangle(792, 612));

var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(docIndex, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~") + "/pdf/Project-" + report.pulledId + currentTime + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

docIndex.Open();
FontFactory.Register("c:/windows/fonts/msmincho.ttc");
StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();
style.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "songti");
style.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);
foreach (var elementIndex in HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
new StringReader(sbsample.ToString()), style))
{
    docIndex.Add(elementIndex);

}
docIndex.Close();
```

Comment: It's very hard to make this work with `HTMLWorker`. It seems that you aren't aware yet that `HTMLWorker` has been abandoned a long time ago. See the [introduction of the HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) for a historic overview. I suggestion that you upgrade to iText 7 + the pdfHTML add-on, and read [chapter 6](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-pdfhtml) of the tutorial.

Comment: There is also a FAQ entry in the tutorial that will be useful for you: [Which languages are supported in pdfHTML?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/which-languages-are-supported-pdfhtml) Note that there are only minor syntax differences between iText 7 for Java (which is used in the tutorial) and iText 7 for .NET. You are still using the old name "iTextSharp" (but you shouldn't: that name has become obsolete as you noticed while tagging this question as an "itext" question).